# how to refresh(reload) page when click button in Jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using Jquery mobile v1.4, how to refresh(reload) page when click button ?

Also which one is loads faster between refresh/reload ?

```
<a href='#' class='btnRefresh'>Refresh</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can try some thing like this**

Call the given JS function on click of your anchor tag

```
function refreshPage() {
  $.mobile.changePage(
    window.location.href,
    {
      allowSamePageTransition : true,
      transition              : 'none',
      showLoadMsg             : false,
      reloadPage              : true
    }
  );
}
```

for more detail click [here](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/reload-the-same-page-without-blinking-on-jquery-mobile/)

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this JavaScript function
`location.reload();`