# jQuery Mobile Refresh the current page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a multi page template in query mobile. How can I refresh the current page on click of a hyperlink or button? I'm using JQM version 1.4.5

I have tried with the following code which suggested in [how to refresh(reload) page when click button in Jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559015/how-to-refreshreload-page-when-click-button-in-jquery-mobile) , however, it is not working as expected:

```
// Refresh the store main page - experimental
$(document).on('click', '#aStoreReload', function (event) {
    $.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        showLoadMsg: false,
        reload: true // tried reloadPage: true also
    });
});
```

It is going back to the main page with URL as it is. I mean `http://localhost:56235/main.html#storeMainPage` in local server. However, [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/munecopujo/edit?html,js,console,output) is displaying a blank page whereas [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ravimallya/x59dyms2/4/) doing nothing. Click on store link to get the page where it has refresh button.

How can I refresh the page (view) in a proper way?

#### Edit

I tried with the following scripts as well on click event:

```
$.mobile.changePage($("#storeMainPage"), { transition: 'slidedown' });
$(document).pagecontainer("load", "#storeMainPage", { reload: true });
```

The first like does nothing and second line gives an error `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on pagecontainer prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'load'` which is normal as we are calling pagecontainer before its initialization.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pagecontainer widget's change method (not load):

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#storeMainPage", function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#aStoreReload', function (event) {
        $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change", "#storeMainPage", {  reload : true, allowSamePageTransition : true, transition : "none" });
    });    
});
```

This will cause the pageshow event to re-trigger.

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x59dyms2/5/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This solution refreshes the page. However, I need to recreate the page. I mean, I have dropdownlists which do some ajax requests on `change` and on `pagebeforecreate` also has some ajax requests. The `reload` should refresh everything on the page. In other word, it should do the functions in `pagebeforecreate` event. Also, if I use the provided code in my page, it will go back to the indexPage again with URL as it is as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Ravimallya, The reload argument only works if the page is in a separate html file.  For me, my code remains on the store page and forces a new pageshow. Just move your ajax creation into the pageshow or pagebeforeshow instead of the pagecreate.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I was able to get what I wanted. See my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about simple:

```
location.reload();
```

Anyway, `$.mobile.changePage` is deprecated:

> Note: jQuery.mobile.changePage is deprecated as of jQuery Mobile 1.4.0 and will be removed in 1.5.0. Use the pagecontainer widget's change() method instead.

[reference](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jquery.mobile.changepage/)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. `location.reload()` will reload the entire HTML page whereas I want to reload the current jquery mobile page into DOM. I don't know how to invoke change event on button click in jquery. The [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#method-load) isn't fair understandable for newbies or the one who learning...

Comment: `$( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer("change",` is the replacement of `$.mobile.changePage`.  `reload()` isn't a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@ezanker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1098622/ezanker)'s answer, finally I was able to reload the page on button click. I have to prefix the page name to the hash to get the page reloaded and re-call all the ajax functions in `pagebforeshow` event.

The code I have used is as below

```
// Refresh the store main page - experimental
//$(document).on("pagecreate", "#storeMainPage", function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#aStoreReload', function (event) {
        $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "main.html#storeMainPage", {
            reload: false,
            allowSamePageTransition: true,
            transition: "none"
        });
        $('#storeMainDesc').text("Latest Store Updates"); // reset the text.
    });
//});
```

Note the changes in code. One filename prefix, second one `reload: false` attribute. If I use the attribute `reload: true`, the previous page would get loaded with the url as it is; i.e. `http://localhost:56235/main.html#storeMainPage`. Don't know what's wrong.